# I want to get a formatted Date in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I want to get a new `Date` object with a `SimpleDateFormat` applied to it.  I would like to do something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy kkmm");
Date today = new Date();
today = myFormat.format(today);
```

I can't do this, because today is a `Date`, and `format` returns a `String`. I also have tried:

```
Date today;
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy kkmm");
try{
    today = myFormat.parse((new Date()).toString());
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

This isn't a good solution, because when I try to use today elsewhere Java complains that today may not have been instantiated.  What is a good way to change the format of a Date object (while still keeping it a Date object, and not turning it to a string)?

Comment: A Date object does not have any associated format, this is why SimpleDateFormat exists... What is your point exactly?

Comment: I am using an interface in which I must pass a Date object.  The Date object needs to be formatted a specific way.  This is my point.  I want to know how to do it so that I don't have to convert from Date to String back to Date.

Comment: These two sentences contradict themselves: "I am using an interface in which I must pass a Date object" -- "The Date object needs to be formatted a specific way". Again, a Date object has _no format_.

Comment: For example the statement: Date today =  new Date("12/12/2011");  Today doesn't have information about things like time zone, hours, minutes, seconds etc.  If this isn't called formatting how would you like me to describe it?

Comment: Do you happen to know that SimpleDateFormat can also _parse_ date strings?

Comment: Yes, that is what my second example above shows.

Comment: Well, then, why doesn't it answer your needs? Why do you try and parse a `Date.toString()`? Why don't you define your SimpleDateFormat with a timezone component?

Comment: Yes, I see I was going about this the wrong way.  I misunderstood the concept of formatting a Date Object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at Format and Date wrongly.

- Date does not contain format. Date is just a class containing date info like date, month, hours, sec etc.
- SimpleDateFormat is the one which tells you the string representation of Date. But there is no date associated with it.

So the idea is when you have to display date or have to store date in some string representation, you will use SimpleDateFormat and pass it the date you want string representation for.

**One benefit** of doing this way is that, I can use same Date object and can show two different string representations (using two different instances of SimpleDateFormat). And also viceversa, having defined one SimpleDateFormat instance, I can format multiple dates.

Edit:

Now if you want to strip some info from the date. Use

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(
   rightNow.get(YEAR),
   rightNow.get(MONTH),
   rightNow.get(DAY_OF_MONTH));
Date now = cal.getTime();
```

There are other good soln like JodaTime

Ref:

[GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)
[Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: For example the statement: Date today = new Date("12/12/2011"); Today doesn't have information about things like time zone, hours, minutes, seconds etc.  This is what I mean by format.  I am currently getting a Date Object but I want some of the data (like seconds) to be dropped off before I send it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve does not make sense.

A `Date` object represents time. You can not format it. But, you can get it's string representation in certain format. Like with `myFormat.format(today)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding something here about what the `Date` object is. `Date` simply holds the information about a point in time - it doesn't have a format at all. When it comes to the `String` *representation* of a `Date`, this is where formatting comes into play. Only worry about the formatting when you are:

1. Parsing a `String` representation into a `Date` object.
2. Converting a `Date` back into `String` representation to display it in a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense. Formatting a date by definition means converting it to a string using a specific format. The `Date` object can stay as a `Date` object. It is only at the point where you wish to convert it to a `String` that you need to do any formatting.

Comment: Well the interface that I am using needs to have a Date Object sent to it.  The Date Object needs to be formatted a certain way (like not having seconds attached to it).  Can you suggest a way in which I can do this?

Comment: That is not formatting, strictly speaking. That sounds more like limiting the precision of the `Date`, for example by ensuring the time component always has a fixed value of 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot associate a format to a Date object instead you can only apply the formats while displaying or other activities,,

Do all processing in the Date object itself and while displaying alone change to the required format,,