# convert string to date object give sunday web, GMT 00+ time i need in date formate dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I am converting string to date object i have string like
2017/3/30. when i parse into date object it gives
 sunday web, GMT 03 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2019
Code is

```
 String dob = "2017/3/30";
     SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM");
            try {
                startDate = format.parse(dob);
                endDate = format.parse(formattedDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I need same formate in date object not string .

Comment: You want same format in output? Actually your question is not clear. You said your original string is `"2017/3/30";` and you want same `"2017/3/30"`???

Comment: yes same formate but object of date not string

Comment: So you want to store a `Date` object, but tou want to take input as a string and give output as a string — have I understood correctly? And you want no leading zero for month and day-of-month in the output, is this correctly understood? So example output could be `2017/3/2` or `2017/12/25`.

Comment: Do you want to use GMT only no matter the computer’s time zone setting? Could be a clever choice.

Comment: take input string and give output as date

Comment: My problem in understanding what you are trying to obtain lies in the fact that a `Date` object doesn’t have a format in it (well, you may say it has an internal format, but that’s encapsulated and shielded; we should not be concerned about it and there’s no way we can change it).

Comment: See also [I want to get a formatted Date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703773/i-want-to-get-a-formatted-date-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

**You need to format it again after parsing**

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM").format(date);
```

Comment: if i add .format(date) after parse like  startDate = format.parse(dob).format(dob); it shows error can't resolve method

Answer (score 0):

The 'format' method returns a String object from a Date object according to the pattern you specified. What you need is the .parse(String) method, which returns a Date from a String.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM");
String yourDate = "2017/03/30";
try {
        Date startDate = sdf.parse(yourDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note that you have to comply with the given pattern, your date must be "2017/03/30". Hope this helps.

Comment: it gives output as Thurs march 02 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2017

Comment: I need Date startDate = 2017/03/30

Comment: I get June 3, 2019. You are getting the 3rd day of th 30th month.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your actual date format, `2017/3/30`, does not agree with the format string you are giving to your `SimpleDateFormat`, `yyyy/dd/MM`. The first has the month in the middle and the day-of month last; the latter has got them the other way around. Therefore the `Date` you get from `dob` is the 3rd of June, 2019 (I think this is what you were trying to say, it wasn’t 100 % clear). `SimpleDateFormat` is understanding your `dob` as the 3rd day of the 30th month of 2017; when there are only 12 months in a year it just continues counting months into 2018 and 2019. It is quite lenient about the values supplied.

You just need to decide on the order of day, month and year. Your question (with the title) mentions 3 different orders, dd/mm/yyyy, 2017/3/30 and yyyy/dd/MM. Once you’re being consistent, your problems will be solved, I expect.

In most cases we don’t want to let bugs like this one slip through unnoticed. The solution to this is

```
    format.setLenient(false);
```

After this call, your date format will no longer accept 30 as a month number, and will report your error back to you so you know and can correct it (and may not need to ask on Stack Overflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

Stop using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

For a date-only value, parse as `LocalDate`.

```
String input =  "2017/3/30";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/m/d" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
```

To assign the first moment of the day, specify a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z );
```

To generate strings representing these values use `DateTimeFormatter`. This has been covered hundreds of times already. So search Stack Overflow for more examples and more discussions.

```
String output = ld.format( f );
```

Comment: To have this work on Android, use the [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/MyDogTom/ThreeTenABP). (ThreeTen because the date and time classes are described in JSR-310, and backport because they were introduced in Java 8 and backported to Java 6 and 7.)