# Issue with String to Date conversion after Timezone parsing

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert a date to a specified timezone and return the converted date. But the code always returns the unconverted date. Can any help with the same.

```
public static Date testUserSpecifiedConv(String toTimezone, Date inputDate) {
        System.out.println(inputDate);
        Date convertedDate = null;
        String inputDateStr ;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(toTimezone));           

        inputDateStr = df.format(inputDate);

        System.out.println("Formatted Date In String Format: " + inputDateStr);
        //Now trying to convert it back to date
        try {
            convertedDate = df.parse(inputDateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertedDate;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Formatted Date In Date Format: "+testUserSpecifiedConv("EST", new Date()));   
    }
```

Output is

```
Fri Mar 31 15:58:50 IST 2017
Formatted Date In String Format: 03/31/2017 05:28:50
Formatted Date In Date Format: Fri Mar 31 15:58:50 IST 2017
```

The formatted date in string and date format in output is different.

Comment: Well, you tell the dateformat to use the timezone EST and hence the date is formatted to that timezone. When parsing it back the dateformat will still use EST hence resulting in exactly the same date. Note that internally a date is represented as a long which are the milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 _UTC_, i.e. regardless of timezone. Hence you can't "convert" a date to a different timezone.

Comment: A `Date` doesn't *have* a time zone. It represents an instant in time. The premise of your method does not make sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: What is the value of `toTimezone`? If it is a three-letter string, you'll likely have problems...

Comment: Answer below deleted as Jon Skeet is here.

Comment: @AndyTurner: as of now it is hardcoded for testing purpose..what sort of problems?

Comment: Note that written dates are just a "label" for any given time instant and timezones are meant to help put that label into perspective. The time instant itself doesn't depend on location, i.e. "now" is now in Berlin, Tokyo, New York etc., although the label for "now" would be different for those locations.

Comment: @EvaMariam what timezone do you think IST is?

Comment: The three-letter time zone abbreviations, many of them are ambiguous. Some take summer time (DST) into account, others don’t even though summer time is used in that zone (or in some of that zone). They recommend you always use the long time zone names (e.g., `Asia/Yerevan`).

Comment: @AndyTurner: indian standard time...?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia’s List of time zone abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations), IST can be either (1) Indian Standard Time, (2) Irish Standard Time or (3) Israel Standard Time (which leaves no reason for me to repeat the A word :-)

Comment: Oh..okay..i did not know all this..mm..Thank you..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `java.util.Date` does represent a specific point in time and is timezone independent per se.

Nevertheless you can apply the timezone to the `SimpleDateFormat` to format your date accordingly to be presented in a certain timezone (e.g. if you want a formatted string to be shown somewhere).

Still, if you now parse back the formatted date, the date object itself will again not contain any information about the timezone.

---

If you want to work with timezones on an object level you might have a look into [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

---

**Update:**
Assuming you want to convert a given `String` to an object containing the information about the date in a certain timezone you could do it like that:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]");
```

Comment: okay..but i just want convert the formated date string back to a date..

Comment: If you convert it back to a date, you will loose the information about the timezone because the date class does not care about that information. Or do you want to convert a given string to a ZonedDateTime?

Answer (score 1):

Date instance does not retain any formatting information. For further details look at the [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703773/i-want-to-get-a-formatted-date-in-java). You will get your answer with a better insight to the Date object.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The [Answer by JDC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43138985/642706) has the right idea.

I will show how to use the modern java.time classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classe (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.) that should be avoided.

Firstly, your two arguments.

- Pass [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) objects around rather than mere strings. Doing so provides type-safety, ensures valid values, and makes your code more self-documenting.
- `Date` is outmoded, convert to [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and pass that instead.

For time zone, specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

For the `Date`, convert to its equivalent in java.time, `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction). Like `Date`, an `Instant` is always in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

To convert between legacy classes and java.time classes, look to new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Assign a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to generate a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Generate a string representing that value using a `DateTimeFormatter`. Do not conflate a date-time object with a string representation of its value.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss" , Locale.US );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```